# Indy 10.6 - idHTTP 100% CPU usage when connecting to Network Stream

Tags: delphi, cpu, indy, indy10, idhttp

I was using Indy 10.5 and several older versions for years. In order to support HTTP Digest Authentication I have downloaded the latest version from their SVN.

This is fixing a HTTP Digest Authentication issue I was having...

The problem is the CPU usage with all the versions since 10.6.

I was able to create 20 threads in parallel to retrieve HTTP Streams (Network Camera MJPEG Streams to be precise) and it was using about 1-3% of cpu per task depending on the resolution and frame rate. (including parsing and decoding)

I have cleaned my code which normally uses IOHandler, CookieManager and relies on the InternalWork method until I'm left with the most basic usage of idHttp that could be that is:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
    HTTPClient : TidHTTP;
begin
  HTTPClient := TidHTTP.Create(nil);
  HTTPClient.Get('http://plazacam.studentaffairs.duke.edu/axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi?resolution=640x480');
  HTTPClient.Free();
end;
```

And even the above code without changing any setting is consuming 25% of CPU (so it saturates 1 core of my computer).

It's an infinite stream so it's normal that it's not returning to the client but since the stream is probably < 100kb/s, the cpu usage for retrieving it should be close to zero...

I have read on another forum in German that adding this HTTPOptions may solve the problem of high CPU but it has no effect on CPU in my case:
HTTPOptions := [hoNoParseMetaHTTPEquiv]

I have tried with the previous releases from Indy SVN to ensure it's not something specific to the daily build.

The 10.6.0 version that ships with XE4,XE5 and X6 has the same problem but If I rollback to:
Indy 10.5.5 - RS2010 RTM

Then everything is fine (apart from HTTP Digest authentication) and it only uses about 2% of cpu...

Did anybody encounter the same and has a way that current version of indy uses reasonable amount of CPU for doing this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about what you are doing.  You are calling the version of `TIdHTTP.Get()` that returns a `String`, but you are downloading an "infinite" stream.  That means `Get()` is constantly reading data from the socket and allocating more and more memory to hold that data in anticipation of eventually converting it into a `String`.  So it makes sense that the CPU usage may be high over time, especially if you multiple that work across multiple threads.

As a test, try telling `Get()` to discard the data it downloads instead of buffering it in memory, and see what the CPU usage looks like:

```
HTTPClient.Get('http://plazacam.studentaffairs.duke.edu/axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi?resolution=640x480', TStream(nil));
```

`TIdHTTP` is not really designed to handle "infinite" streams, unless you provide a `TStream` that is able to receive "infinite" data (like `TIdEventStream`), or enable the `hoNoReadMultipartMIME` flag if the server is using MIME to deliver the streaming data, in which case you can read the streaming data yourself as described in this blog article:

[New TIdHTTP hoNoReadMultipartMIME flag](http://indyproject.org/Sockets/Blogs/ChangeLog/20140305.EN.aspx)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. I will give this a try. As workaround I have found a 10.5.8 version which works fine with my scenario and where HTTP Digest is working as expected.

Comment: Btw, in my "real" scenario the stream is constantly flushed so it never grows over 32kb. I'm intercepting it in the InternalWork and doing what I need with the result...

Comment: I made the test and you're right adding TStream(nil) as return stream makes the cpu drop to normal usage for this (0-1%) so I will mark your reponse as answer. Since what I'm retrieving is actually Multipart content, adding the hoNoReadMultipartMIME flag doesn't help because .Get() directly returns. I would still like to know what changed between 10.5.x and 10.6.0 since I can use the default internal Stream (HTTPClient.Response.ContentStream) while using almost zero cpu... I will see if I find a way with different types of stream to have the same performances as I was used to.

Comment: Read the blog article I linked to in my answer, it explains how to use `hoNoReadMultipartMIME`. If the server is streaming the video using MIME, then that flag is exactly what you should be using. You *want* `Get()` to exit, then you are free to read the streaming data yourself as needed.

Comment: I went through the article and will read it again and give a try to this approach. I already have everything in place to deal with multi-part on my own and it was working perfectly with multiple cameras running 24/7 for several weeks so I may keep current solution with 10.5.8 but I will try to compare. At least I have 2 options now, a few hours ago I had nothing :) Thank you!